# Is isDefined() being deprecated and did isNull() take its place?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using ColdFusion 9.0.1

I recently read that in ColdFusion 9, it is now advised to use [`isNull()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0-3c4c0bb81223f1daffb-8000.html) and not use `isDefined()`.

I didn't find much info on this at all around the web.

Is there any advantage to using one or the other in ColdFusion 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that in general people have been moving away from it for some time. The main use for it was to determine whether a variable existed in a particular scope, but structKeyExists() is more precise for that. IsDefined() works very hard to find any possible instance of the variable you've asked for. ([Sean Corfield had a bit to say about structKeyExists vs. isDefined](http://corfield.org/entry/isDefined_vs_structKeyExists).)

I've not seen anywhere a recommendation to use isNull() instead of isDefined. Actually, I would have expected isNull to return an error if you give it an undefined variable, but apparently that works.

How do you do dynamic variables, though?

```
structKeyExists(form,"address_" & i)
```

You can try array notation...

```
isNull(form["address_" & i])
```

...but if `i` is undefined this throws an error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am using structKeyExists(SCOP, "ASDF") quite regularly now.

Answer (score 6):

No, isDefined() is not deprecated and won't likely be deprecated.

IsNull() is for, as Shawn says, for working with NULLs returned from Java, most specifically for those returned from Hibernate (ORM integration).

StructKeyExist() is more precise than isDefined("") but there is, technically, nothing wrong with using isDefined() and I would question whether or not structKeyExist() would work in every situation. Is every variable within a struct or some sort? I am not sure.

I do not think you need to worry about isDefined() going away anytime soon.

Comment: I actually prefer your use of StructKeyExists, Jason. Seems an overall cleaner way to refer to variables that may or may not exist--and blanketing your CF code with isDefined() is prone to unseen issues, like typo-ing the name of a variable you are checking the existence of.

Comment: Since CFMX, all variable scopes are structs.

Comment: In CF7 and CF8, what scope are var-scoped function variables in? I think in CF9 they are in the LOCAL scope, but that did not exist in CF7 and 8, right?

Comment: Personally I am still using `isDefined` almost only for testing XML parsing results, to avoid nested `StructKeyExists` nightmare.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the real reason isNull() was added was to provide a more concrete way to test for Java-related NULLs that are returned from objects, services, etc--whereas isDefined() tests to see whether a variable exists or not.

Two separate functions, really.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `isDefined(varName)` my `CLIENT.somevarname` variable has a null value, and when I try to evaluate it

> `<cfif isDefined("somevarname") and val(somevarname)>   </cfif>`

.. it throws an error :

> Element somevarnameis undefined in CLIENT

I use to handle it like this to prevent an error when conditionally comparing the value:

```
   len(trim(CLIENT.somevarname)) eq 0
```

I switched to using `isNull()` and it works better.

Comment: 1) Why use `evaluate()` at all? 2) What is wrong with using `structKeyExists(client, "keyName")`?

Comment: Yes, that works fine if we use the client structure and you want to find the key, however, I've been getting null values in a structure from an API Response. So your structKeyExists would evaluate as true and still have a null value.

Comment: Oh wait, I see some of the code did not display due to the tags. (Tip: use the code `{}` button to format cfml). Also, the cfif variable names do not match the error message. Did you mean `<cfif IsDefined("Client.ShowSavingsBadge") and val(Client.ShowSavingsBadge)>` ?

Comment: *RE: I've been getting null values in a structure from an API Response*  Ah, so it is an actual `null`? In that case, yes - `IsNull` is the correct function to use.